# Titanium iOS app crash on launch using Titanium sdk 8.0.0 and iOS sdk 12.1

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio

I have just updated iOS sdk from 11.4 to 12.1 and Titanium sdk from 7.3.1 to 8.0.0 because of min sdk requirement by App Store. But now my app is crashing after update as soon as i launch my app. App works fine when run through Appcelerator Studio on iOS Simulator but crashing when run through titanium created iphone-build project on xCode iOS simulators and also on actual devices no matter if built through xCode or Appcelerator Studio.

Here are the logs i get through xCode.

```
2019-05-03 18:22:03.518724+0500 Eczema[32972:344754] libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:890: MGIsDeviceOneOfType is not supported on this platform.
2019-05-03 18:22:03.519668+0500 Eczema[32972:344754] [DEBUG] Reading stylesheet from: /Users/sabasoft/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6D7BEC66-2C66-4B03-89DF-7EE701161D74/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/EDC0AC40-5E88-4E5C-A4E0-D8D386A8E10E/Eczema.app/stylesheet.plist
2019-05-03 18:22:03.716883+0500 Eczema[32972:344754] [INFO] Eczema/1.0 (0.0.0.(null))
2019-05-03 18:22:03.777071+0500 Eczema[32972:344754] [DEBUG] Loading: /Users/sabasoft/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6D7BEC66-2C66-4B03-89DF-7EE701161D74/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/EDC0AC40-5E88-4E5C-A4E0-D8D386A8E10E/Eczema.app/ti.main.js, Resource: ti_main_js
2019-05-03 18:22:03.780580+0500 Eczema[32972:344754] [INFO] Eczema 1.0 (Powered by Titanium 8.0.0.3726240fa2)
2019-05-03 18:22:03.781163+0500 Eczema[32972:344754] [DEBUG] Loading: /Users/sabasoft/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6D7BEC66-2C66-4B03-89DF-7EE701161D74/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/EDC0AC40-5E88-4E5C-A4E0-D8D386A8E10E/Eczema.app/_index_.json, Resource: _index__json
2019-05-03 18:22:03.782424+0500 Eczema[32972:344754] [DEBUG] Loading: /Users/sabasoft/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6D7BEC66-2C66-4B03-89DF-7EE701161D74/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/EDC0AC40-5E88-4E5C-A4E0-D8D386A8E10E/Eczema.app/ti.internal/extensions/Error.js, Resource: ti_internal/extensions/Error_js
2019-05-03 18:22:03.787079+0500 Eczema[32972:344754] [ERROR] Script Error Couldn't find module: core-js/modules/es6.date.to-json for architecture: x86_64
2019-05-03 18:22:03.788907+0500 Eczema[32972:344754] [ERROR] Application received error: Couldn't find module: core-js/modules/es6.date.to-json for architecture: x86_64

TitaniumKit 0x000000010a4fd3ca -[KrollBridge loadCommonJSModule:withSourceURL:] + 449
TitaniumKit 0x000000010a4fdd23 -[KrollBridge loadJavascriptText:fromFile:withContext:] + 68
TitaniumKit 0x000000010a4ff13c -[KrollBridge require:path:] + 400
TitaniumKit 0x000000010a5366a2 CommonJSRequireCallback + 106
JavaScriptCore 0x00000001053c5b9f _ZN3JSC19APICallbackFunction4callINS_18JSCallbackFunctionEEExPNS_9ExecStateE + 495
??? 0x000049862fc0102d 0x0 + 80840675561517
JavaScriptCore 0x000000010539a33d llint_entry + 26817
JavaScriptCore 0x00000001053938fe vmEntryToJavaScript + 244
JavaScriptCore 0x000000010588e36a _ZN3JSC11Interpreter14executeProgramERKNS_10SourceCodeEPNS_9ExecStateEPNS_8JSObjectE + 11178
JavaScriptCore 0x0000000105ab9a20 _ZN3JSC8evaluateEPNS_9ExecStateERKNS_10SourceCodeENS_7JSValueERN3WTF8NakedPtrINS_9ExceptionEEE + 288
JavaScriptCore 0x00000001053c4ff5 JSEvaluateScript + 501
TitaniumKit 0x000000010a4fc0f7 -[KrollBridge evalFileOnThread:context:] + 823
TitaniumKit 0x000000010a53528c -[KrollInvocation invoke:] + 79
TitaniumKit 0x000000010a535df5 -[KrollContext invoke:] + 109
TitaniumKit 0x000000010a4fc220 -[KrollBridge evalFile:callback:selector:] + 55
TitaniumKit 0x000000010a4fcc85 -[KrollBridge didStartNewContext:] + 1808
TitaniumKit 0x000000010a5365ff -[KrollContext main] + 1084
libdispatch.dylib 0x000000010be98595 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
libdispatch.dylib 0x000000010be99602 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
2019-05-03 18:22:03.790291+0500 Eczema[32972:344754] [ERROR] Script Error Module "ti.internal/extensions/Error.js" failed to leave a valid exports object
2019-05-03 18:22:03.791419+0500 Eczema[32972:344754] [ERROR] Application received error: Module "ti.internal/extensions/Error.js" failed to leave a valid exports object

TitaniumKit 0x000000010a4fc173 -[KrollBridge evalFileOnThread:context:] + 947
TitaniumKit 0x000000010a53528c -[KrollInvocation invoke:] + 79
TitaniumKit 0x000000010a535df5 -[KrollContext invoke:] + 109
TitaniumKit 0x000000010a4fc220 -[KrollBridge evalFile:callback:selector:] + 55
TitaniumKit 0x000000010a4fcc85 -[KrollBridge didStartNewContext:] + 1808
TitaniumKit 0x000000010a5365ff -[KrollContext main] + 1084
libdispatch.dylib 0x000000010be98595 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
libdispatch.dylib 0x000000010be99602 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
libdispatch.dylib 0x000000010bea699a _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1541
CoreFoundation 0x000000010b2203e9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
CoreFoundation 0x000000010b21aa76 __CFRunLoopRun + 2342
CoreFoundation 0x000000010b219e11 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 625
GraphicsServices 0x000000010d9dd1dd GSEventRunModal + 62
UIKitCore 0x00000001177cb81d UIApplicationMain + 140
Eczema 0x00000001050df59b Eczema + 9627
libdyld.dylib 0x000000010bf0f575 start + 1
2019-05-03 18:22:03.792083+0500 Eczema[32972:344754] [DEBUG] Application booted in 143.831968 ms
```

can anyone help me on this. What is the issue here?

Comment: Going to leave this as a comment because it doesn't fully address your issue. Titanium manage a JIra instance and have this ticket: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-26807 saying that running the Xcode project directly is not supported and should be assumed to not work. Stick to titanium studio ... or better yet, go native like I did lol

Comment: Thanks. But it crash when built through titanium studio also. I only moved to xCode because i want to see app logs for crash.

Comment: there is no reason to ever compile through xcode, just package using Appcelerator Studio, vscode/atom plugins or better: CLI